# Inserting data trouble with my code

Tags: php, html, mysql, post

Hi i was using this code in the last months but suddenly it stop working and it doesn't store the data in the database, it's config with the auto increment value and it just stopped in the "87" after that i can't make it to work

```
    <?php 
$connect = mysql_connect("host","user","pass");//database connection
if($connect){
    echo("+");
}else{
    echo("-");
}

$make = mysql_select_db("database");
if($make){
    echo("+");
}else{
    echo("-");
}

// Get values from form 
$renovarum=$_POST['repnovarum'];
$cargorepnov=$_POST['cargorepnov'];
$razonsocial=$_POST['razonsocial'];
$rfcli=$_POST['rfcli'];
$representante=$_POST['representante'];
$cargorepcli=$_POST['cargorepcli'];
$nombrecomercial=$_POST['nombrecomercial'];
$calleynum=$_POST['calleynum'];
$calle3=$_POST['calle3'];
$calle5=$_POST['calle5'];
$calle6=$_POST['calle6'];
$calle4=$_POST['calle4'];
$personafm=$_POST['personafm'];
$escritura=$_POST['escritura'];
$fechaescr=$_POST['fechaescr'];
$abogado=$_POST['abogado'];
$numnotario=$_POST['numnotario'];
$ciudades=$_POST['ciudades'];
$numcomer=$_POST['numcomer'];
$fechapro=$_POST['fechapro'];
$emailcont=$_POST['emailcont'];
$liderproyecto=$_POST['liderproyecto'];
$fechainicio=$_POST['fechainicio'];
$fechavencimiento=$_POST['fechavencimiento'];
$entregables=$_POST['entregables'];
$inforeq=$_POST['inforeq'];
$pago=$_POST['pago'];
$pago2=$_POST['pago2'];
$formadepago=$_POST['formadepago'];
$diaspago=$_POST['diaspago'];
$fecprimerpago=$_POST['fecprimerpago'];
$telefono=$_POST['telefono'];

//inserting data order
$order = "INSERT INTO contratos_finales2
       (repnovarum,cargorepnov,razonsocial,rfc,representante,cargorepresentante,nombrecomercial,calleynum,colonia, ciudad,estado,cp,tiporeg,numescritura,fechaescritura,nombrenotabo,numnotpub,ciudadescr,numpropycom,fechaproycom, emailcont,liderproy,fechaini,fechafin,entregables,inforeq,cantnum,canletra,formadepago,diadepago,fechaprimerpago,telefono)
      VALUES
       ('$renovarum','$cargorepnov','$razonsocial','$rfcli','$representante','$cargorepcli','$nombrecomercial','$calleynum','$calle3','$calle5','$calle6','$calle4','$personafm','$escritura','$fechaescr','$abogado','$numnotario', '$ciudades','$numcomer','$fechapro','$emailcont','$liderproyecto','$fechainicio','$fechavencimiento','$entregables','$inforeq','$pago','$pago2','$formadepago','$diaspago','$fecprimerpago','$telefono')";

//declare in the order variable
$result = mysql_query($order);  //order executes
if($result)
{
 echo("
+");
}
else
{
 echo("
-");
}
?>
```

i need to keep saving the data in the form but i can't make it work i don't know if i have to make a change i didn't change anything in the database it's te same version and connection from the beginning.

Comment: Do you have any error messages?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the data type of your auto increment field, it may possible that your `data type` is `tiny int` or have `less length`. You need to change your `datatype` to `INT` and length as 11 or as per your requirement.

Comment: i will check that the auto increment it's in INT but the length it's in 10 i will change it thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your code is vulnerable to sql injection. Who knows what one did to your database. At least do a minimum sanitization with mysql_real_escape_string();
Can you add data to your table from phpmyadmin via UI? Any error messages? Try to run your query in phpmyadmin's cmd tool.

Comment: i know but it's inside the intranet so we don't pay to much attention to the security thanks for your comment i will make some security changes

Answer (score 0):

please correct this

```
       $make = mysql_select_db("database");
```

```
    $connect = mysql_connect("hostname","username","password");//database connection

    $make = mysql_select_db("database",$connect);



    bool mysql_select_db ( string $database_name [, resource $link_identifier = NULL ] )
```

[please take a look here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php)